# Can one rely exclusively on Adobe for Flex/Flash RSL's (to avoid using own bandwidth)?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, rsl

If you have limited server resources and expect a lot of traffic to a Flash site, is there a way of NOT having to serve Run-Time Shared libraries, but rely on Adobe to do this for you?

For example, if you want to make sure "framework_4.0.0.14159.swz" is always fetched from "fpdownload.adobe.com" and not from your own server, what modifications should be made to the config section:

```
<runtime-shared-library-path>
    <path-element>/opt/flex4/frameworks/libs/framework.swc</path-element>
    <rsl-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/flex/4.0.0.14159/framework_4.0.0.14159.swz</rsl-url>
    <policy-file-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml</policy-file-url>
    <rsl-url>framework_4.0.0.14159.swz</rsl-url>
    <policy-file-url></policy-file-url>
</runtime-shared-library-path>
...
<static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>false</static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>
```

Also, is there any reason this might be a bad idea?

Please notice, I am using the command-line compiler, mxmlc.exe (not Flex Builder).

UPDATE:
I guess my issue is more about the errors I get at run-time than the above question. In fact, the reason Flash tries to download from my server to begin with is that the Adobe download fails (see error messages in my comment). I am therefore going to accept the below answer and, if I don’t succeed in solving the problem, I might open up another question.

Comment: By the way, I currently get these errors (from my local flash log):
[START]> Error #2034: An invalid digest was supplied.
> Failed to load RSL http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/tlf/1.0.0.595/textLayout_1.0.0.595.swz
> Failing over to RSL textLayout_1.0.0.595.swz
> Error #2034: An invalid digest was supplied. [END]
This started happening after I cleared the local Adobe AssetCache to check that things were working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [Using the framework RSLs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7add.html):

> Note: You can point to the SWZ files
>   that are hosted on the Adobe web site,
>   rather than deploy your own SWZ files
>   as RSLs. In this case, view the
>   default entries for the RSLs in the
>   flex-config.xml file to see how to
>   link to them.

Comment: But what are you supposed to do exactly? My quote above is in fact one of the default entries from the flex-config.xml. But my Flash player chokes with "Error #2034: An invalid digest was supplied". This started happening after I cleared the local Adobe AssetCache to check that things were working.

Comment: Restart your browser (and maybe computer).  Once you clear the cache it takes a total Flash Player restart to actually take effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you never should - adobe.com does go down sometimes, or the client maybe allowed access to your site and not Adobe's (because of a corporate firewall, for instance).

Comment: well... i mean, adobe.com is a massive site.  it's much MUCH more likely that a $100/year webserve from godaddy.com (for example) will be down temporarily.  remember, that RSLs are cached.  they're not downloading code every time the user uses the software.

Comment: The second part is a lot more likely, yes.